# Difference in meaning - 'started climbing' v 'has been climbing'

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, time, present-perfect-progressive

What is the difference between them:

- He **started climbing at the age of 11**.
- He **has been climbing since he was 11**.

For me they are same and I don't see difference.

Comment: Do you mean "age of 11" and "since he was 11"?

Comment: I have two. He has been climbing since he was 11 and he started climbing at the age of 11

Comment: I don't know the second is continuing or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He started climbing at the age of 11.

> He has been climbing since he was 11.

The meaning is almost identical, but there are differences of nuance.

The following sentence makes sense:

> He started climbing at the age of 11, then stopped when he was 15.

The following would be nonsensical:

> *He has been climbing since he was 11, then stopped when he was 15.

You could, however, say:

> He has been climbing since he was 11.  He stopped when he was 15, but started again a year later.

"He has been climbing" implies that he still climbs.  "He started climbing" doesn't tell us one way or the other.